# How to select li dropdown text with keyboard arrow keys (without mouse click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to select element or row from li dropdown with keyboard arrow keys. Please see the screenshot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SFYw.png)

If you see the image, there is column Ledger Name in table. When I am typing drodown is coming but not able to select it by keyboard arrow keys.

These values are coming from database table i.e. search functionality is implemented through AJAX call to JSP page.

Please help me on this.

Below is the JQUERY function code written for this :
Below is the code for AJAX call & setting data to ul from db table.

It is written in Jquery & AJAX. JSP is used to get data from database

```
$("#tbody").on("keyup", "input[name^=inputString]", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var search = $(this).closest('tr').find("input").val();   
    if (search != '' && search != null) {
      $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'ledgers.jsp',
                  data: 'key=' + search,
                  success: function(data) {
                    $this.next('#showList').html(data);
                  }
      });
    } else {
              $('#showList').html('');
           }
    });
   });
      
   $("#tbody").on('click', 'li', function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').find("input").val($(this).text());
     $(this).closest('tr').find('#showList').html('');
   });
```

Comment: Please include code of how this is being developed so that the best answer can be given.

Comment: If you're writing your own custom drop down, then you need to write your own custom handlers/events.   You might be better using a pre-built (and pre-tested (and pre-including functionality you hadn't thought of)) such as [tag:select2] or similar.

Comment: Check the code in question written for AJAX call & append data from db to ul list:

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon,

You could take a look at the [datalist element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

That way the functionality is built in.

PS: here's some good examples with [styles](https://dev.to/siddev/customise-datalist-45p0)

---

As for how to accomplish this with `<li>`

1. have an event listener on you input element for `onFocus` that performs step 2
2. attach the `onKeyDown` even listener to listen for up/down/and enter keys
3. then you can keep track of a counter knowing what element to highlight, `down-arrow -> +1, up-arrow -1`
4. make sure that `0 < count < options.length`, by either cycling or clamping, whichever makes more sense for your usecase.
5. and pressing enter would replace the value in the input element with the selected element

Anyways, that is just one way to implement this feature, hopefully you'll just use the `datalist` and save yourself a lot of time ;)

Comment: Can u share the code if u have it